# Having a hard time with the present tense for informative situations

Tags: grammar, tenses

Ok imagine you're somewhere to fix things(e.g. there is a ticket), and then you need to update the status that you fixed it, for example an IP(internet protocol), should I use present tense or past tense.

I think I should use the present tense.
in my case I have to let them know that I made an IP static, but the tricky part here is I don't wanna use the "I" subject so I want it to be sound more passive.

"199.1.1.1 is made static!"  <- it's a fact and I am saying it!! I am not sure, I think this one is the correct way

Or

"199.1.1.1 was made static!" <- this means it was static but not anymore or we don't know if it's static anymore, if I am not wrong?!so this can't be right!

or

"199.1.1.1 has been made static!" <- to my understanding this means this ip is made static at some point in the past, and it's still static, correct me on this, I think it sounds off this one?!, I am so confused.

Comment: *199.1.1.1 has been made static* is correct for the reasons you mentioned: you made it static upon a recent request, and it was still static at the very moment you said that. (But the present perfect promises nothing beyond the present moment.)

Comment: right! thx, but why present tense is wrong, present tense suppose to be used for sharing facts, e.g. sky is blue, this ip is made static,
it means "Everyone who is watching this ticket, this ip is become static, it's no longer dynamic.",
it's more like a news, who made it happen we don't know, when did it happen we don't know, but this ip is static, and somebody caused it ofc(passive),
that passive here I think also helps the sentence to get a more recent(timeline) action to itself.



what message/info present tense is not carrying here?

Comment: “This IP is now static.”

Comment: and that's my other question, what if we don't use the keyword now, doesn't present tense has an implicit now at the end of the sentence automatically?

Comment: In terms of closure messages for job tickets "199.1.1.1 made static" would be quite acceptable to most colleagues and managers. As the job was assigned to you, you are closing the ticket, and you are writing the closure note then other people will assume that you made the change to the status of the IP address.

Comment: boldben ok exactly! so can we elaborate a bit more on this?, because I am kinda learning English too, so this is a simple past, and I am really confused, it's totally feels appropriate, but what I am seeing here, this structure(the way you used) of simple past makes sense, but the way I used it, it doesn't "199.1.1.1 was static"<- this means it was but not anymore or we're unsure, "199.1.1.1 made static" <- implies based on the context I m using it for ofc, means the change on this ip from dynamic to static was made successfully..,

Comment: therefore you can also use the past tense and carry the same meaning!?

Comment: The present tense doesn't work here: *199.1.1.1 is made static!* You could say: *199.1.1.1 is now static!* Or: *199.1.1.1 is static!*

Comment: If the IP was ALREADY static, then you would say something like, "No change made to IP - already static." A ticket status is presumed to be a recording of actions that someone performed -- so use past tense.